# Function returns 0 when float number is under 1

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have this code to calc the diference between the main branches of a binary tree, the important thing is the final. Debugging I get to the last expression:

```
return difRama/total;
```

this will always return a decimal between 0 and 1 as percentage it is.
I get situations like:

- return 5 / 15
- return 4 / 10

  ```
  float Arbol::diferenciaRamas(pnodo rama1, pnodo rama2){
      int total, difRama, pesoIzq, pesoDer;

      /* Calculamos pesos rama izq yder*/
      pesoIzq = pesoRamificaciones(rama1);
      pesoDer = pesoRamificaciones(rama2);

      /* Diferencia de peso entre ramas */
      difRama = abs(pesoIzq - pesoDer);

      /* Total de peso del arbol */
      total = (pesoIzq+pesoDer);

      /* Si el total es 0 o la diferencia es 0 */
      if(total == 0 || difRama == 0)
          return 0;

      /* Porcentaje de diferencia */
      return difRama / total;

  }
  ```

The problem is that the function always returns 0, any idea?

Comment: In C++, how you use a result does not affect how it is computed. That your function returns a `float` does not change how `difRama / total` is computed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The division occurs **before** the implicit conversion from `int` to `float`.

You need an explicit cast from `int` to `float` before the division.

```
return (float)  difRama / total;
```

You should know by operator precedence rules that the above cast applies to `difRama` before the divide (rather than to the result of the divide).

Comment: To clarify: that cast applies to `difRama`. Once `difRama` has become a `float`, the compiler will convert `total` to `float` so that the argument types for the division match. The cast does not apply to the expression itself; `(float)(difRama/total)` would still do integer division, then convert the result to `float`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was reviewing my own post deciding whether that clarification was needed when your comment appeared.  So I guess that clarification was needed.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to convert something. The compiler can also convert things without a cast; that's an implicit **conversion**.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've seen and used "implicit cast" quite often and I thought the meaning was clear.  But I'll trust your claim that "conversion" is a better word.  So I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're computing the division in integer arithmetic. This happens if both arguments in the division are integral types, irrespective of the type of variable to which the result is assigned.

A simple fix is to pre-multiply the quotient by `1.0f`:

return `1.0f * difRama / total;`

which will force the arguments to be promoted to `float`s.

Altenatively (which I prefer), multiply by `1.0`, which will force the arguments to be promoted to `double`, and the entire expression will undergo an implicit narrowing conversion to `float` when returned.

Comment: Well, I just uprooted. I guess folks prefer casts to additional numbers. But there's nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd use the cast myself, but I don't see why people think this is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the variables difRama and total are both of type int. If the result has a fractional part (0.33 in your first situation and 0.4 in the second one), it will be truncated. But if you explicitly convert one of them to float, then truncation will not happen. Like this:

```
return static_cast<float>(difRama) / total;
```

Comment: While it's true that casting both to `float` will produce the desired result, it's only necessary to cast one of them. The compiler will convert the other to match.